# 'then' function is not never getting called by Mocha for assertion checking

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, q, sinon, chai

I have written the following test case in Mocha, where the my code uses `Q` module.

```
var expect = require("chai").expect;
var utils = require("../Utils.js");
var utils1 = require("../a.js");
var sinon = require('sinon');
var request = require('requestretry');
var querySys = require('../b.js');
var Q = require("q");

describe("Sample", function () {
    var results;
    describe("#get()", function () {
        before(function (done) {
            done();
        });
        it("equal", function () {
            var deferred = Q.defer();
            var responseData = {};
            responseData.code = 200;
            responseData.data = [{a:1,b:2}];
            deferred.resolve(responseData);
            //querySys1 method uses Q promises. That is how I stubbed the response.
            sinon.stub(querySys, 'querySys1').returns(deferred.promise);

            //get function internally calls querySys1. Hence I have stubbed that.
            results = utils1.get(specification);
            results.then(function (data) {
                //Here I do see data coming as {in:1, out:1}. But still the test case is passing when compare it with {}.
                console.log(data);
                //Ideally, it should have failed. But it is passing.
                expect(data).to.be.equal({});
            });
        });
        after(function (done) {
            done();
        })
    });
});
```

So, if you see, I am trying to do assertion check in `results.then` part. I have printed the response, which I am receiving. That is coming as expected. **But I am intentionally trying to match with wrong value, but test case is still passing.**

Answer (score 0):

Since your test does not include a callback, execution runs through the main block and declares the test as passing without waiting for the result of the `then` function. You need to let mocha know to wait for the callback:

```
it("equal", function (done) {
    ...
    results.then(function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        expect(data).to.be.equal({});
        return done();
    });
});
```

Comment: Now it is throwing the following error: `Error: timeout of 2000ms exceeded`. But even though I get the result in less time. Because `console.log(data)` print the output very quickly.

Answer (score 0):

When I changed `results.then` to `results.done`, test started failing as expected. Can someone say whether this is the right approach.